# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Routes') in React with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm building a React application and encountering the following error:

`react-dom.production.min.js:121 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Routes') at Object.get [as Routes]`

I'm using React with React Router for routing in my application. Here's how I've included the necessary scripts in my layout.html:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/6.22.3/react-router-dom.development.js" integrity="sha512-V3xj7BgT+v9+QCAOo3yhwq0ybFqPVET7K/IZmKMnWjjeEXrbXLXR3dKC/KQRN42F4KLkIUed3/4aUus5p5L3nQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.0.4/js.cookie.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

In my App.js, I'm attempting to use React Router as follows:

```
const App = function () {
  const { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } = window.ReactRouterDOM;

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Tweet />}>
          <div>
            <Tweet />
          </div>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<App />);
```

Versions:
React: 18
React Router DOM: 6.22.3
I've tried destructuring BrowserRouter separately, which works fine, but when I include Routes alongside BrowserRouter and Route, I encounter the mentioned error.

Any insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!